# Dynamically set input still makes the form invalid

Tags: javascript, angular

I have three input boxes that are all required. 1st input box is Quantity which is manually entered, the second is Computed based on the (input) method of 1st input (quantity/total), and the 3rd input is the Total that is dynamically set (from DB). Dynamically setting of those inputs are working fine.But after auto setting the Computed and Total, the form is still invalid, how can I make the form valid because both boxes have values already, that were set dynamically.

form.component.html

```
<mat-form-field class="w-10-p" appearance="outline">
     <input  matInput 
         formControlName="quantity" 
         type="number"
         (input)="computeValues(i, $event)"
         required>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field class="w-10-p" appearance="outline">
     <input  matInput 
          formControlName="computed" 
          [id]="'computed'"
          type="number"
          required> 
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field class="w-10-p" appearance="outline">
      <input  matInput 
            formControlName="total" 
            [id]="'total'"
            type="number"
            required> 
</mat-form-field>
```

form.component.ts

```
computeValues(index,event){ //iluvJS
        var quantity=event.target.value;
        let total = (document.getElementById('total') as HTMLInputElement).value;
        var size = Math.round((parseFloat(total) / quantity) * 100) /100;
        (document.getElementById('size') as HTMLInputElement).value=size.toString();

    }
```

The form still acts as if those inputs are still empty.

Comment: Don't use `document.getElementById('size') as HTMLInputElement).value` to set values, use form controls instead

Comment: You are setting value in the html, but you are not setting it in the Form.

Use form.get([ path to control ]).patchValue(value) i.e form.get(['total']).patchValue(30)

Comment: @xyz Thank you for that Sir. I am new to angular and I really don't get the whole concept of form controls or what exactly do you mean. Could you give me any link that help me understand it? Sorry if you find the request stupid.

Comment: @code4funN4treasure Docs from https://angular.io would be your best guide. To answer your question, Qellson has already answered it in his comment.

Comment: @code4funN4treasure why don't you use **form.patchValue**?

Comment: you can use this.formname.controls.fieldname.setvalue(value)

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it like this (use **patchValue** if you have to update some controls and use **setValue** if you want to change all controls)

```
this.yourForm.patchValue({
  total: 50,
  size: '123'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function code should be like this.

```
this.computeValues(index,event){ //iluvJS
    var quantity= this.formname.controls.quantity.value;
    let total = this.formname.controls.total.value;
    var size = Math.round((parseFloat(total) / quantity) * 100) /100;
    (document.getElementById('size') as HTMLInputElement).value=size.toString();
    this.formname.controls.size.setValue(size);

}
```